# How to use the sum function in Python3

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the sum function multiple times after one another but I keep getting a error message. I wrote the following code:

```
averages["averages_home_goals"] = sum(d['home_goals'] for d in averages.values() if d)
averages["averages_away_goals"] = sum(d['away_goals'] for d in averages.values() if d)
averages["averages_home_conceded"] = sum(d['home_conceded'] for d in averages.values() if d)
averages["averages_away_conceded"] = sum(d['away_conceded'] for d in averages.values() if d)

print(averages)
```

The averages variable looks like the following:

```
{
    'Belconnen%20United': {
        'home_goals': 4.0,
        'away_goals': 1.0,
        'home_conceded': 0.0,
        'away_conceded': 2.1666666666666665,
    },
    'Canberra%20FC': {
        'home_goals': 1.75,
        'away_goals': 1.8,
        'home_conceded': 2.0,
        'away_conceded': 2.0,
    },
    # More data of a similar structure
}
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

The weird thing is; when I run only one of these 4 lines the code executes fine (I doesn't matter which line). I'm getting the error upon executing the `averages["averages_away_goals"] = ...` statement

Could anyone help me out? Giving variable d another name also doesn't work

Comment: I would ask "What is `averages`" but I assume you have a good reason for not showing it or explaining what it is and what you're trying to do. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: which line is the error ?

Comment: Looks like you have a dictionary of dictionaries, but the code isn't saying so. Please show us what `averages` is, or even just with the values changed.

Comment: @cs95 Added averages

Comment: @GeeTransit Added the variable output

Comment: Don't use `averages` to create your average dict, use another dictionary and the code will work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first line will work just fine, but the failing will start on the second line and continues onwards. The reason is that you have included a new entry in the `averages` dictionary after the first line. Hence your `averages` dictionary has a new key `"averages_home_goals"` with a single float value.

When you execute the second line, you iterate through all the values of the dictionary `averages`, which now has an additional value of the sum of all home goals in the key `"averages_home_goals"`, which is going to be a float. And you cannot subscript a float. Basically what it means that you are trying to execute an example of a code (on the second line) of these sorts:

```
12.3242["away_goals"]
```

which will always fail.

As a solution I'd suggest to store the results into a new dictionary, f.e.

```
res = {}

res["averages_home_goals"] = sum(d['home_goals'] for d in averages.values() if d)
res["averages_away_goals"] = sum(d['away_goals'] for d in averages.values() if d)
res["averages_home_conceded"] = sum(d['home_conceded'] for d in averages.values() if d)
res["averages_away_conceded"] = sum(d['away_conceded'] for d in averages.values() if d)

print(res)
```